# When is the x++ evaluated?

Tags: java, operators

In

```
int x = 5;
int answer = x++ * 6 + 4 * 10 / 2;
```

the output is 50, and but why the ++ operator doesn't evaluate the expression to 51?

Comment: How can the output be `50`? `0*6+4*10/2 = 0+40/ 2= 0+20 = 20`

Comment: @BackSlash is right, you must do the division before the moltiplication

Comment: Note that `x = 5` before the calculation, not `0`, so the answer is indeed `50`, not `20`.

Comment: @Jesper before the edit x was 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `++` is on the `x` not the result.

> why the ++ operator doesn't evaluate the expression to 51?

Can you explain how or why that would work?  If you wanted that just do

```
 int answer = x * 6 + 4 * 10 / 2 + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment is using the postfix operator which increments after the statement is executed.

The JLS mentions this:

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the
>   variable before the new value is stored.

For more details see the [full specification entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2).

Comment: @RohitJain Your right the statement doesn't evaluate to 51, I assumed the order of operations was correct otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Postfix operator is evaluates after execution of statement.
According to [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or after (postfix) the operand. The code result++; and ++result; will both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is that the prefix version (++result) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix version (result++) evaluates to the original value.

Answer (score 0):

The defined effect of the ++ postfix operator is that the variable `x` gets incremented, as if you wrote `x = x+1`, but the value of the expression `x++`is the value *before* the increment. If you want to have th esame effect regarding how `x`changes, but use the *after* avlue in the surrounding expression, you need to use `++x`. And if you actually didn't want to increment the contents of `x` at all, use `(x+1)`.

(It is however not defined, I think, when the assignment of the incremented value  to `x` takes place - it might even be afer `anwser` obtains its value; on the other hand, usually `x++` is almost atomic.)